# Pandas: unable to load Pickle file after upgrade (0.22 to 0.23):

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

as in the title, I get this error while loading a pickled file:

```
AttributeError: Can't get attribute '__nat_unpickle' on <module 'pandas._libs.tslib' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/_libs/tslib.cpython-36m-darwin.so'>
```

This file was correctly loaded with the previous version.
How can I get the file correctly loaded, apart from switching back to Pandas 0.22?

I work on a Jupyter notebook on MacOS High Sierra 10.13.4, Python 3.6.3.

Thank you!

Comment: Having same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying to load the pickle file through `pickle.load`? If so, I would suggest loading it though `pandas.read_pickle` which has additional logic to preserve backwards compatibility with older pickle files.